# Is it enough to read manuals?

Tags: unity, blender, books

I want to develop games with Blender and Unity. I don't see any good books out there and so I'm considering reading the manuals of both the software. Should reading the manuals be enough if you're creative enough to figure out how to get a game working if you know how everything works?

Comment: If you don't see any good books about Blender and Unity, clearly you are not looking at the right place... These are two of the most used softwares for game development, there should be a ton!

Comment: I didn't mean good books in the sense that they don't teach you to make games. I meant that they don't teach you everything there is about both software.

Comment: Look up some tutorials of simple beginner stuff in each, and use the manuals later on.

Comment: I was thinking the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing beats practice. Reading the manuals will give you a good start at knowing what features exist and how to use each one individually. But generally, what you want to do is not available in text books so you have to figure out how to assemble parts of what you know to achieve the result you're looking for.

That's where practice comes in. And forums. And stack exchange. Or a teacher. Or a colleague. And youtube. And practice.

So, to answer: **It is good to read manuals, but it is not enough to get good at it.**

Comment: +1. Text books and manuals only give you guidelines, or tools. But using and combining them to make the game you want is a matter of practice and experience.

Comment: Practice automatically comes in when I start making the games. But the manuals should be enough to inform me about all the buttons and knobs and whatnot that are around the interface. Often with tutorials and books, they just tell you to click something and change a value but don't explain what it does. Even if it does, they explain it from the perspective of the current problem and not in context of generality.

Comment: That sir, answered my question.

Comment: @user3143420 then feel free to accept his answer by... accepting his answer :) click the tick icon below the upvote count. This will give him more reputation, hence increasing his likeliness of answering similar questions from beginner users like yourself:)